# Structure of sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

The translation of

> "I hope you will forward my profile to your team."

is

> "Ich hoffe, Sie leiten mein Profil an Ihr Team weiter."

"leiten" is direct and "weiter" is further according to google. So the literal German to English translation is

> "I hope you direct my profile to your team further".

Is "leiten" used in the sense of "forward"? I suppose so but I am not sure. What is the use of "weiter"?
Where is the future tense used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here, “weiter” and “leiten” are two parts of the separable verb “weiterleiten”, which means “to forward”. Separable verbs in German are similar to phrasal verbs in English, but with the fun features that their infinitives  are actually written as one word and that when they are separated the first part can move to the very end of the sentence.

Both parts of the sentence are in the present tense, German often uses the present tense to describe the future, more often than English.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123940/discussion-on-answer-by-carsten-s-structure-of-sentence).